# compare data from an array with numeric ID and insert it into a datagrid

Tags: c#, arrays, datagrid

I have a single array with random numbers as shown below

```
int[] numbers = new int[5] {2,5,3,7};
```

Also I have a table in my database with id and name in the ID have the same numerical values ​​to my array.

- 2 , Pedro
- 5 , Juan
- 3 , Claudio
- 7 , Gonzalo

I need to do is compare the numbers in the array with the id of the database, and if these are equal, showrange name associated in a datagrid

What thought is using a For loop on the array so,

```
for (int i = 0; i <numbers.length; i + +)
```

and show and thus obtain the names '`select value from table where id =' + numbers[i];`

I need too much help, hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have valid connection you can use classes like SqlDataAdapter, DataTable and SqlConnection to fulfill a table with data you want. You also may use slightly different query to get results. Look at this code:

```
string numList = string.Join(",", numbers.Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToList());
// you need to have connection initialized with connection string
SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("select value from table where id in (" + numList + ")", connection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();// the result goes here
a.Fill(dt);// actually querying the database
```

That's it - you now have all your names from database which are corresponding to the list of IDs you have supplied. Now you can show that list in datagridview or datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

So the question can be reduced to the ADO.NET part, how to retrieve the `value` from the `id`:

```
string sql = "SELECT value FROM dbo.table WHERE id = @id";
var pairs = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
using (var con = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    con.Open();
    foreach (int i in numbers)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", i);
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(i, dr.GetString(0)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have used a `List<Tuple<int, string>>` as collection to store all ID's and according names which you can use as datasource or further processing(i don't know if you only want to show the id's which have a name in your table). You can access the ID + name in this way:

```
foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
    int id = pair.Item1;
    string name = pair.Item2;
}
```

Note that i've used the `using`-statement to ensure that all unmanaged resources are getting disposed as soon as possible. That will also close the connection.

Always use parameters to prevent sql-injection or conversion issue even if you are currently not vulnerable to it.